# Create Excel Checklist from new weekly files?

Tags: excel

Summary: I was wondering if it is possible to create a running file that would contain columns by week and that a value would be added to the weekly column only in the row that had activity that week.

More detail: Each week I have a new file that has multiple line items for customers. I want a check list file that Column A would be all the customers, and each other column is week ending date. 
Each week when I put all my data into the weekly file, I want it noted in this checklist file which customers appeared for that week. While to weekly file is blank before customer data is added, it is a saved template with formulas to manipulate the data

I tried to do a pivot table, and it worked for a single week, but couldn't figure out how to get each week added to same pivot table, and to get the customers to line up n the same row. It was also a lot of manual work. I'd like to add a formula to the weekly file to automatically tell it to report to the check list.

I am also intrested in learning if excel can be set up so that when a file is run from an accounting software, an exsisting excel file will know what to do with it.
Any help would be great

Comment: I'd love to take the time to give you a solution to this. Excel is definitely powerful enough to do everything you've requested here. However, I'm incredibly busy right now. Perhaps you could start by looking at [external links](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'push' a result into another cell/sheet/book with a formula. Maybe I don't understand the question. Does not mere presence in the weekly list provide sufficient indication that 'it' is required on the check list? What version of Excel? Have you tried LOOKUP? An example below:

[image: SO9485678]